# Exchange Online Hybrid Deployment w/ Public Folders

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, public-folders, exchangeonline

We are looking to move our exchange environment to exchange online. I have been trying to find information on how we can continue to utilize our extensive public folders. I know that exchange online does not support public folder, though the will with 2013. I know we have the option to use SharePoint online, or group mailboxes. We have decided not to do this as part of the migration to exchange online if we can avoid it.

My question is; with a hybrid deployment with a 2010 information store on site, would we be able to house our public folders there and will our users hosted in exchange online be able to access them?

I have been searching MS for an answer on this, but have not been able to find anything one it.

Thanks for any assistance,
Robert

Comment: Probably should look at my answer on this post http://serverfault.com/questions/413768/exchange-online-hybrid-deployment-w-public-folders/761675#761675

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can keep Public Folders on premises and have them visible to migrated users.  It ain't easy, but it is possible.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249373(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Welcome to server fault!  While this is certainly helpful, it's even better if you give a brief explanation of the procedure or concepts outlined in the linked document.

Comment: ... so if the link dies, the answer doesn't become useless :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a no for current Exchange Online:

> Public folders are not supported in Office 365 and **Exchange Online mailboxes will not have access to public folders located in the on-premises Exchange organization**. Existing on-premises public folder configuration and access for on-premises mailboxes will not be changed in a hybrid deployment.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852527

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite old now, but I thought I'd share what we're doing in our O365 deployment:

In our environment we have replaced public folders with shared mailboxes. As long as they adhere to the shared mailbox size limits (5GB), a license is not required.

Comment: A license is required for using Public Folders on O365? Maybe this might be the cause of our issues in question https://serverfault.com/questions/955088/public-folders-company-setup-are-not-showing-for-migrated-users-in-e2010-o365-hy ...