# Public Folders company setup are not showing for migrated users in E2010/O365 hybrid environment

Tags: exchange-2010, public-folders, exchange-hybrid

We have a hybrid environment setup between Exchange 2010 and O365 for both mailboxes and Public Folders. Since putting Public Folders in hyrbid mode (with Public Folders beta turned on in Azure AD Sync, and following https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/collaboration-exo/public-folders/set-up-legacy-hybrid-public-folders for mail enabled public folders, the latter of which does work) we have only been able to see the non-unique part of the Public Folder hierarchy, not our folders, in migrated users.

i.e., Public Folders

- All Public Folders
- Favorites

... is all migrated users see, not MANY folders under All Public Folders like non-migrated users still see.

I have tried giving the mail enabled public folders both Exchange and Office 365 licenses in the Microsft 365 admin center, and googling, without luck. What am I missing?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/collaboration-exo/public-folders/set-up-legacy-hybrid-public-folders

Comment: @joeqwerty - See edit.

Comment: What edit?.....

Comment: What version of Outlook are users using?

Comment: @joeqwerty The insertion of the link you provided, that was actually already used to provide mail enabled folder syncing.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Have only tested on Outlook that is part of the Office 365 suite (¿2019?), as this is the version we will be moving people to prior to migrating their mailboxes from on-prem to O365. 1901 (Build 11231.20174) was the version I am testing on, if helpful.

Comment: 1. Make sure you didn’t miss any steps in official article.
2. Make sure that you have upgraded Outlook to the latest version.
3. Please check if you get any errors in AAD connect, then check if you can see the PF in Office 365.

Comment: @JayceYang - 1) Went over it twice before posting. 2) Currently using the O365 version of Office, which has had "Check for updates" done every day. 3) No errors in AAD connect, and mail enabled public folders are receiving mail.

Comment: Did you configure the public folders as favourite in outlook? if yes, please use MFCMAPI to remove them and test.